# Sending Email Through PHP

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to create a forum where a user completes it and places their email on the forum so I know who it came from. Once completed, I validate and send the contents of the forum to my email address but I'm not getting any emails from the site.

Here is my HTML

```
<article class="contact" id="contact">

    <div class="contact-content">

                        <div class="span5 contact-info">

            <!-- Contact title -->
            <div class="contact-title">
                                        <h2>Contact</h2>
                                </div> 



            <div class="contact-scroll">                


                                                <p>Address: 123 Baker Street</p>
                                                <p>Phone Number: (555) 555-555</p>
                                                <p>E-Mail: example@gmail.com</p>

                <div class="class1" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
                <div class="class2">
                <div class="class3" style="position: absolute; top: 0px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                <div class="class4" style="position:relative;"></div></div><div class="class5"></div></div></div>

                <!-- contact form -->
                <div class="contact-form" style="margin-top: 10px;">

                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <input style="width: 185px; float:left; font-size:14pt; color: white; b" type="text" name="your-name" id="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name" aria-required="true" placeholder="Full Name">
                            <input style="width: 185px; float:left; font-size:14pt; color: white;" type="email" name="your-email" id="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email" aria-required="true" placeholder="Email Address">
                            <input style="width: 374px; font-size:14pt; color: white;" type="text" name="your-subject" id="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject" placeholder="Company Name">
                            <textarea style="color: white; width: 373px;" name="your-message" id="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message" aria-required="true" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="Submit">


                        </form> 

                </div>  


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>



</article>
```

Here is my php

```
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $name = $_POST["your-name"];
    $email = $_POST["your-email"];
    $companyName = $_POST["your-subject"];
    $message = $_POST["your-message"];

    $to = "sendto@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $subject = $name." from ".$companyName." just emailed from online CV";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "Mail Sent.";
}
```

The "if" statement is executing properly because the echo is outputted. I've also tried to pass the values to an alert box and all the input values are displayed in the alert box using this php code. The only problem is I can't get it to email the inputs to the email address I've specified in my php code. I'm running this site on 000Webhost free servers. Is the a script I have to include in my index.php to make the mail function work? Do I have to configure something inside the control panel on my 000Webhost account? Or is this simply just a syntax error?

Thanks

Comment: Try without the headers first, see what happens.

Comment: hi, you ask 000Webhost hosting ?

Comment: What's the boolean result from `mail()`? You should be doing `if(mail(...)) { echo "mail sent"; } else { echo "mail error"; }`

Comment: Have you set up mail correctly in your PHP configuration ?

Comment: i looked up to google and got many problems. https://www.google.cz/search?q=000webhost+mail+php+not+working&oq=000Webhost+mail&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.5071j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Form element names cannot contain hyphens, use underscores instead. E.g.: `your-name` change to `your_name` including any references of the same `$_POST["your_name"]` etc., then do it for the others also. I will not post this as an answer, you can do this yourself, and theoretically if everything goes according to plan, it will work.

Comment: OK first off thank you everyone for commenting and providing me with great suggestions. Thomas, I've tried without the headers and got the same result unfortunately. daremachine, No I didn't ask them. Don't really expect them to give much of a reply anyways.@jszobody The boolean value was true meaning the message must have been sent but I've not received (and yes I've tripled checked the email address to make sure it is indeed correct). Aidan, Didn't know I had to set up mail in my PHP configuration. How do you do that? @Fred I removed the hyphens but no luck.

Comment: I did seem to have the email sent to my hotmail account though! It works when I use my hotmail but not mt gmail account. -_- Does anyone know why and how I can fix that? I even tried checking my spam folder on my Gmail account but it's not there.

Comment: since  000Webhost hosting is free hosting ,they may stop sending email from their server ,so please check clearly with suppport peoples of  000Webhost hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I just managed to figure this out. To make this work on gmail, I had to add extra stuff to my headers.

```
$headers = "From: {$email}\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: {$email}\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Path: {$email}\r\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP5\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-encoding: 8bit\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Importance: 0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers .= "Delivered-to: {$to}\r\n"; 

$subject = $name." from ".$companyName." just emailed you";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"; 
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
 echo "Mail Sent.";
}
else
{
echo "Mail was not sent!";
}
```

These extra headers are needed to have mail sent to Gmail accounts. Everything else from my original code worked fine as is.